# SVN : how to get information about revisions

Tags: svn, revisions, mergeinfo

I use the 'svn mergeinfo' command to fetch information about the changes that should be merged from branch to trunk. This command returns only the list of revisions, for example:
r18427
r18428
r18429
...

I would like to fetch also the comments that are added during committing those changes to svn to prepare such kind of output, ex:
r18427 - "the code was formated"
r18428 - "added a procedure to ..."
r18429 - "removed one redundant variable"
...
Do you know how to get detailed information about revision, what is a command that can do this ?

Thanks for any help and suggestion,
rafi

Answer (score 1):

You can use the svn log command to get comments for a specific revision. With a little scripting you can get the comments for the list of revisions returned from the mergeinfo command

```
svn log <repo url> -r <rev #>
```